# How to say "give to my girlfriend's mother" in Russian?

Tags: падежи, местоимения

I know how to use possessive pronouns in Russian:

> *Это моя книга.*

I also know how to describe a person's possession:

> *Это книга подруги.*

But how do I combine two persons, such as in this example:

> *I want to give this book to my girlfriend's mother.*

I don't know what to search for. How is this called in linguistic terms?

Which linguistic cases do I use here for the words `girlfriend` and `mother`?

---

My guess would have been:

> *Я хочу подарить эту книгу маме моей подруги (на Рождество).*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You guess is absolutely correct, technically there's an other valid option:

> Я хочу подарить эту книгу подругиной маме.

But while this is grammaticaly valid talking of specifically word `подруга` it's very unlikely one will choose second form over the first one - `подругиной` sounds clumsy.

But I've mentioned this because in some cases, for instance, with personal names, it's exactly the opposite, second form, like in:

> Я хочу подарить эту книгу Лениной маме.

is more preferable compared to

> Я хочу подарить эту книгу маме Лены.

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste. Personally, I wouldn't use this form (`Лениной маме`). It only works for diminutive names, so it's mostly used colloquially.

Comment: I have seen that before with personal names, e.g. in ``Где будет отдыхать семья Светланы в выходные дни?``. At first, I was unsure about that sentense and thought it's the family's name, but then I realized its actually a first name, thus "the family of Swetlana". Thanks for pointing that out as well.

Answer (score 14):

Your guess is both grammatically  correct and idiomatic:

> Я хочу́ подари́ть э́ту кни́гу ма́ме мое́й подру́ги (на Рождество́).

You used the dative case for ма́ма -> ма́ме 'to mother' and the genitive case for подру́га -> подру́ги 'of girlfriend.'

You can stack up genitives to describe more complex relations:

> Подру́га бра́та однокла́ссника мое́й сестры́
>
> My sister's classmate's brother's girlfriend OR
>
> The girlfriend of the bother of the classmate of my sister

Nowadays most people prefer де́вушка to say girlfriend. Thus your sentence would be:

> Я хочу́ подари́ть э́ту кни́гу ма́ме мое́й де́вушки.

If you get married, you'll be entitled to call her mother тёща. Mentioning just this word alone to a Russian (or Google) can get you lots of jokes.

Comment: Thank you Sergey. I accepted shabunc's answer, because it is more to the point, slightly better readable and he simply answered first. Though, I appreciate your effort and the additional information you provided. I would accept both answers, if I could.

Comment: @user1438038 My pleasure. I added another answer because I felt that a few points from your question needed addressing: "how do I combine two persons" and what grammatical cases can be used. Glad you liked my answer.

Comment: @user1438038, Sergey has noted a very important point here about the word "girlfriend". In modern Russian подруга does not imply, oh well... a girlfriend relationship, it's just a female friend.

Answer (score -1):

Я хочу дать эту книгу матери моей девушки.

Answer (score -1):

A possible option:

```
Я хочу подарить эту книгу моей (будущей) тёще.
```

(I want to give this book to my future mother in law.) It may sound a bit kinky, but uses the feature of Russian that in-laws can be called by one word.